# Sending multicast data to group members listening on different ports

Tags: sockets, udp, multicast

If I have multicast group members 239.0.0.1:1000 and 239.0.0.1:2000, is it possible to send data from a source to these two members in a single multicast ? Is there any C function available to send to both these sockets in a single call ?

EDIT:

This is my scenario.
I have n number of hosts. For simplicity let's take 5 hosts (A, B, C, D and E) are there. These hosts are listening on ports 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and 5000 respectively. Now say, A has children B and C, B has children D and E. C, D and E have no children. What I want to do is, grouping the children in a same multicast group, so that a parent can send data in a single transmission. Also, a child sends data to it's parent using unicast message. Since, these nodes are already listening for unicast data on the mentioned ports, I am looking for a way to add these ports to a multicast group (thereby avoiding  creation of a new socket in each host).

Comment: No. Why are they listening on different ports? Fix that.

Comment: @EJP Actually I already have two hosts listening for data on 1000 and 2000. These nodes receive unicast data on these ports. Now I am trying to find a way to send data to these two hosts without creating any other socket for multicast. Is there any other way to do this without creating a new socket ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and comment don't make sense. Nodes receiving unicast data on ports 1000 and 2000 won't receive multicast data at all. You'll have to recode them to join the multicast group, so that would be your change to unify the port numbers. You don't have any choice about that.

Although if there are only two hosts, multicast seems scarcely worth while at all.

Comment: Doesnt change anything. You have to use a single port for multicasting.